# How to 'unwrap' Publisher object in view [swift]

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift5, combine

How would I go about assigning the array contents to a variable for use in the view.

```
struct SwiftCameraApp: App {
     @StateObject var service = CameraService()
     var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            Home()
                .environmentObject(service)     
     }
}

public class CameraService: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var videoClips = [URL]()

    public func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {
        print("finished recording the video to: \(outputFileURL)")
        print(output.recordedDuration)

        videoClips.append(outputFileURL)
            
        //returns 1 at this point
        print("\(videoClips.count) video clip is now in the camera service")
}

struct ViewA: View {
    @StateObject var model = CameraService()
     Button("Adds item to videoClips") {
            model.fileOutput()
        }    
}

struct ViewB: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var service : CameraService
    var body: some View {
        Button("Prints Array count") {
            print(service.$videoClips.count())
        }
    }
}
```

Output:


Count(upstream: Combine.Published<Swift.Array<Foundation.URL>>.Publisher(subject: Combine.PublishedSubject<Swift.Array<Foundation.URL>>))


Maybe helpful to know.

a) When the CameraService is initiated videoClips is empty. A value is added AFTER the button is pressed in view A.


b) I think when the view is initialized a new CameraService is created making it an empty array


c) The idea is to take a video. Append it to a videoClips array and then do something with the contents in view B.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just wanted (ie. number of elements in array):

```
    Button("Prints Array count") {
        print(service.videoClips.count)
    }
```

**Update:** it is used different object of `CameraService` in `ViewA`, so updating `ViewA` nothing changed in `ViewB`, because instances of model not the same.

Instead you need to use reference to same `CameraService`, ie. that one provided in environment object

```
struct ViewA: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: CameraService   // << here !!
     Button("Adds item to videoClips") {
            model.fileOutput()
        }    
}
```

Comment: prints 0 even know I know there are values in the array

Comment: Would you provide minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

Each one of `@StateObject var model = CameraService()` is a separate instance of of the Service.
The one in `SwiftCameraApp` cannot see what `ViewA` is doing and Vice versa.

If you want them to communicate past along using `EnvironmentObject` from `SwiftCameraApp`>`Home`>`ViewA` or you can change your service to be a singleton.

```
public class CameraService: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    static let shared = CameraService()
    @Published var videoClips = [URL]()

    private init(){}

    public func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {
        print("finished recording the video to: \(outputFileURL)")
        print(output.recordedDuration)

        videoClips.append(outputFileURL)
        
        //returns 1 at this point
        print("\(videoClips.count) video clip is now in the camera service")
}
```

And change your `StateObject`s to `@StateObject var model = CameraService.shared`